# How do I create new columns using a mutate and for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I tried the following:

```
pathogens <- c("Adenovirus", "Coronavirus NL63", "Coronavirus HKU1", "Coronavirus 229E", "Coronavirus       OC43", "Human Metapneumovirus", "Human Rhinovirus/Enterovirus", "Influzena A", "Influzena A/H1", "Influzena A/H3", "Influzena A/H1-2009", "Influzena B", "Parainfluenza Virus 1", "Parainfluenza Virus 2", "Parainfluenza Virus 3", "Parainfluenza Virus 4", "Respiratory Syncytial", "Bordetella parapertussis", "Bordetella pertussis", "Chlamydia pneumoniae", "Mycoplasma pneumoniae")
               
for (value in pathogens) {
  df_nphl_combined2 <- df_nphl_combined %>%
    mutate(!!value := if_else(str_detect(Results, value),1,0))
  print(value)
}
```

Doing this only adds one column to my dataframe which contains the last pathogen.

My objective is to run through the Results column of the dataframe and using str_detect to find each pathogen then create a column putting the number 1 if the patient has that pathogen or 0 if the patient does not.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` to create new column for every `pathogens`. Try

```
library(tidyverse)

df_nphl_combined2 <- bind_cols(df_nphl_combined, 
                        map_dfc(pathogens, 
                       ~df_nphl_combined %>% 
                         transmute(!!.x := as.integer(str_detect(Results, .x)))))
```